How can I use \thequestion, \thepartno and \themarginpoints while printing sulutions sepererated from and before the questions in Exam class?
I would like tot print the solutions seperatly from the questions. To be more precise: before the questions.
I found a way to do it at Answers at the end of the exam document, but there goes something wrong with \thequestion, \thepartno and \themarginpoints. They are either ignored or printed as '0'. See picture.

Any ideas how to fix it? Or another approach the reach my goal?
\documentclass[answers, addpoints]{exam}

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{endnotes}

%SOLUTIONS
\unframedsolutions
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\textbf{\thequestion\thepartno \quad maximumpoints \themarginpoints}\\}

%SOLUTIONS BEFORE QUESTIONS
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\def\makeenmark{\relax}
\def\notesname{}
\def\answer#1{\endnotetext{\begin{solution}#1\end{solution}}}
\def\theanswers{\theendnotes \medskip}

\begin{document}

    \ifprintanswers 
        Solutionssection\\
        \theanswers \newpage
    \else \fi

    Questionssection
    \begin{questions}
    
        \question
        Some introduction to this question.
            \begin{parts}
                \part[4]
                This is a question which has a maximum of four points.
                    \answer{The answer to this question.}
            \part[3]
                This is a question which has a maximum of three points.
                    \answer{Another answer.}
            \end{parts}
            
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}


@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. I got rid of a lot of irrelevant information.
